# Filter two arrays Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter

I have one empty array and two arrays with data

```
var resultsArray = [String]()

var array1 = ["1","2","2","3","4"]
var array2 = ["1","2","2","3","4","5","6"]
```

My goal is to append the `resultsArray` with the elements from `array2` that don't match `array1` ("5" and "6" in the example).

What's the subtlest way to do so?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what you mean by "don't match". Do you mean the values in `array2` that aren't in `array1`? What if `array2` has three "4"s—should two of them go in `resultsArray` or zero? Or do you mean values that don't match at the same place—so `[1, 2, 3]` and `[3, 1, 2]` would have 1, 2, and 3 in `resultsArray`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the `filter` function

```
var resultsArray = [String]()

let array1 = ["1","2","2","3","4"]
let array2 = ["1","2","2","3","4","5","6"]

let filteredArray = array2.filter{ !array1.contains($0) }

resultsArray.appendContentsOf(filteredArray)
```

If the collections contain unique items consider to use `Set` rather than `Array`

---

Update Swift 5.1:

In iOS 13, macOS 10.15 there is a new API in `Array`

`public func difference<C>(from other: C) -> CollectionDifference<Element> where C : BidirectionalCollection, Self.Element == C.Element`

---

```
var resultsArray = [String]()

let array1 = ["1","2","2","3","4"]
let array2 = ["1","2","2","3","4","5","6"]

let diff = array2.difference(from: array1)
resultsArray.append(contentsOf: array1)
for change in diff {
    switch change {
    case .remove(let offset, _, _): resultsArray.remove(at: offset)
    case .insert(let offset, let element, _): resultsArray.insert(element, at: offset)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the exact solution i've been looking for. Thanks, vadian!

Comment: It should be noted that this has a computational complexity of O(n^2) and it might be needlessly slow if the arrays get larger. Consider using a Set instead where the `contains` methods is O(1) rather than O(n)

Answer (score 2):

```
var resultsArray: [String] = []

let arrayX = ["1","2","2","3","4"]
let arrayY = ["1","2","2","3","4","5","6","7"]

let setX = Set(arrayX), setY = Set(arrayY)

resultsArray.append(contentsOf: setY.subtracting(setX))
```

This answer is faster than using filter.

Comment: Would be nice to have some explanation

Comment: @Ivan this is the same answer but done with set subtraction

Comment: 0.00490117073059082 vs 0.0463278293609619 in time measurments. My answer is faster.

Comment: You need to add this to the post. Without explanation one will need to visually compare two answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use filter function for the purpose to find the different number of elements in the both array

```
let Filter = array2.filter{!array1}
resultArray.appendContentsof(Filter)
```