# How can I remove values array based on array other

Tags: arrays, swift

How can I remove values array based on array other.

**Example** :-

*Type ( Int )*

> var arrayOne = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>
> var arrayTwo = [1,2,4,5,6,7]

---

I want the next result :-

> result = [3,8]

Comment: Check this [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29852086/3589771).
Browser before asking a question in StackOverflow.
StackOverflow also has an option for documentation. 
In your case check this [documentation for `set`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/371/sets/1632/performing-operations-on-sets#t=201707120506132185625)

Comment: There is much resources to read about array manipulation with a simple google search. read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680135/filter-two-arrays-swift#comment59040041_35680166

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Set for simple result

```
var arrayOne = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

var arrayTwo = [1,2,4,5,6,7]

let set1:Set<Int> = Set(arrayOne)
let set2:Set<Int> = Set(arrayTwo)

let set3 =  set1.symmetricDifference(set2)
```

**Output :**

{3, 8}

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by converting them to Sets.

```
var arrayOne = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
var arrayTwo = [1,2,4,5,6,7]

let set1:Set<String> = Set(arrayOne)
let set2:Set<String> = Set(arrayTwo)
```

Use **ExclusiveOr** to do this.

```
    //Swift 2.0
    set1.exclusiveOr(array2) // result = {3,8}

   //Swift 3.0
   set1.symmetricDifference(set2) // result = {3,8}
```

This link might useful for you: [Set operations (union, intersection) on Swift array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589181/set-operations-union-intersection-on-swift-array)
also possible Duplicate as @user3589771 said.

Answer (score 0):

Use following working code -

```
let arrayOne = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
let arrayTwo = [1,2,4,5,6,7]
var result = [Int]()

for value in arrayOne
{
     if !arrayTwo.contains(value)
     {
         result.append(value)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with below options.

**// Option 1 - Using Set's**

```
let arrayOne : Set = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

let arrayTwo : Set = [1,2,4,5,6,7]

var result = arrayOne.symmetricDifference(arrayTwo)

print(result) // {3,8}
```

**// Option 2  - Using Array**

```
var result1 = [Int]()

for value in arrayOne
{
    if !arrayTwo.contains(value)
    {
        result1.append(value)
        }
    }

print(result1) // {3,8}
```